# 'Can not perform an aggregate function on an aggregate or a subquery' error on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
Select A.nEvrakKalemID As ID, 
  A.cEvrakKalem As [Inventory Name],
  SUM((IsNull((Select SUM(B.nMiktar) Where B.nEvrakTip = 3 or B.nEvrakTip = 7),0)) - (IsNull((Select SUM(B.nMiktar) Where B.nEvrakTip = 4 or B.nEvrakTip = 8),0))) As Inventory
From MasrafAnaliz.dbo.EvrakKalem A 
Left Outer Join MasrafAnaliz.dbo.EvrakKalemHareket B
On B.nKodEvrakKalem = A.nEvrakKalemID
Group By A.nEvrakKalemID, A.cEvrakKalem, B.nMiktar
Order By A.nEvrakKalemID
```

In the above question I want to sum up the `Inventory` column and group it according to the column `nEvrakKalemID`. 
But it does not work.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
Select A.nEvrakKalemID As ID, 
       A.cEvrakKalem As [Inventory Name],
       (SUM(CASE  WHEN B.nEvrakTip = 3 or B.nEvrakTip = 7 
                  THEN (IsNull(B.nMiktar,0))
                  ELSE 0
            END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN B.nEvrakTip = 4 or B.nEvrakTip = 8
                 THEN IsNull(B.nMiktar,0)
                 ELSE 0
            END)) As Inventory
From MasrafAnaliz.dbo.EvrakKalem A 
Left Outer Join MasrafAnaliz.dbo.EvrakKalemHareket B On B.nKodEvrakKalem = A.nEvrakKalemID
Group By A.nEvrakKalemID, A.cEvrakKalem, B.nMiktar
Order By A.nEvrakKalemID
```

Comment: I will try and inform you. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query should be

```
SELECT
  A.nEvrakKalemID AS ID,
  A.cEvrakKalem AS [Inventory Name],
  SUM(ISNULL((SELECT
    B.nMiktar
  WHERE B.nEvrakTip = 3
  OR B.nEvrakTip = 7), 0) - ISNULL((SELECT
    B.nMiktar
  WHERE B.nEvrakTip = 4
  OR B.nEvrakTip = 8), 0)) AS Inventory
FROM MasrafAnaliz.dbo.EvrakKalem A
LEFT OUTER JOIN MasrafAnaliz.dbo.EvrakKalemHareket B
  ON B.nKodEvrakKalem = A.nEvrakKalemID
GROUP BY A.nEvrakKalemID,
         A.cEvrakKalem,
         B.nMiktar
ORDER BY A.nEvrakKalemID
```

Using `CASE` will be the better option.

Comment: Thank you for your interest.